# Как узнать hardware-id чужого компьютера?

Tags: javascript, php

Всем доброго вечера. Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли каким то способом узнать hardware-id чужого компьютера? Или это миф?

Comment: А что такое hardware-id в вашем понимании? (Или в понимании тех, кто вам про это рассказал)

Comment: Hardware ID (HID) — это идентификатор вашего компьютера, который формируется на основании данных о вашем оборудовании. В комплекс этих данных входят многие компоненты, такие как материнская плата, оперативная память, процессор, жесткие диски и так далее. В результате для каждого компьютера формируется свой уникальный идентификатор. Не исключены редкие совпадения, но это сотые доли процента в общей массе компьютеров.

Comment: Так это ещё и чисто виндовая штука. Я знаю только один способ: спросить владельца компьютера.

Answer (score 0):

> идентификатор вашего компьютера, который формируется на основании данных о вашем оборудовании.

Тогда используйте библиотеку JavaScript Fingerprint и там будет хеш, который по сути и является собирательным образом железа

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ. обязательно попробую данную библиотеку